# How to get or update in a form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

**What I am trying to do :**
I am trying to update the LogDone object in my view when the form is save.

The logdone was already created before, I want to use the id of the logdone previously created and update instead of creating a new one.

```
def create_logdone(request, logmessage_id, log_id, token ):
    log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
    logmessages = get_object_or_404(LogMessage, pk=logmessage_id, logbook=log)
    logdone = LogDone.objects.update_or_create(logmessage=logmessages)
    form = CreateLogDone(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.done_by = request.user
            instance.logmessage = logdone
            instance.save()
```

**Error I get**

> "LogDone.logmessage" must be a "LogMessage" instance.

Comment: `instance.logmessage = logdone` likely does not make much sense? Shouldn't this be `instance.logmessage = logmessages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass it as instance to the `CreateLogDone` form:

```
def create_logdone(request, logmessage_id, log_id, token ):
    log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
    logmessage = get_object_or_404(LogMessage, pk=logmessage_id, logbook=log)
    logdone, __ = LogDone.objects.update_or_create(logmessage=logmessage)
    form = CreateLogDone(request.POST, instance=logdone)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.done_by = request.user
            form.save()
            # …
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `CreateLogDoneForm` instead of
> <s>`CreateLogDone`</s>.

Comment: Another error occur with your code `'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'`
Thanks for your time

Comment: @Mcflan_g: is there a line in your code that ends with a comma?

Comment: No, the error come from the instance=logdone but i don't know why

Comment: @Mcflan_g: because `.update_or_create(..)` returns a 2-tuple. You can write `logdone, __ = ...` to obtain the first element (and throwaway the boolean that specifies if the object is create/updated).

Comment: Exactly, well done and thank you, I will bookmark this question lot of good advice and tips !